# Does the order in which you finish Broken Age (Act I) affects the ending?

Tags: broken-age

Again, I must stress, severe "Broken Age" spoilers.

I've finished Broken Age (Act I) by first playing with Vella, switching to Shay near the end, and after finishing with Shay - getting back to the last few puzzles with Vella.

> When I've finished with Shay - the game ended with Shay fainting on the outside of the ship. When I've finished with Vella - the game ended with Vella fainting on the beach, and then meeting Shay and 'switching places' with him. If I would've finished the game with Vella - would the game ended with her fainting, and the final sequence appearing only after I've finished with Shay?

Would the final sequence be different in any way?

(Just to be clear - this is the [ending sequence](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYqeITpDTJY) I've seen)

Comment: I've specifically tested this on a second playthrough of the backer-only alpha version. What you see after finishing one half of the story is not affected by how far you got with the other part of the story. I.e. the cutscene will always play after finishing Vella's story.

Comment: On the 'final' version, it doesn't happen this way. Since asking this question I've been able to verify the accepted answer myself (my wife finished the Vella portion of the game first, and I've been watching over her shoulders when she did - the cutscene did not appear, with the game switching to Shay after Vella faints)

Comment: Ah, very nice! I hoped they would "fix" that before the release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem to: (skip to around 16:00)

I finished the same way you did, but this walkthrough shows what happens if Vella finishes first. Seems to be exactly the same, just in a different order.

> I.e., each character's fainting is where they leave off, and then both rejoin for the final cutscene.